# Instant Hummus Pre-cooking without Dehydrating

Tags: flour, dehydrating, chickpeas, hummus, outdoor-cooking

I would like to prepare my own instant hummus (dried, only add water) for backpacking. A commercial [product](https://outdoorherbivore.com/instant-hummus/) is available, but I would prefer to start from scratch.

Normally, chickpea flour has to be cooked for around 3 minutes to make hummus, e.g. in this [recipe](https://www.food.com/recipe/chickpea-flour-besan-hummus-318052).

I would like to avoid cooking the flour in a large amount of water, as [dehydrating](https://backcountrycooking.blogspot.com/2010/02/dehydrated-hummus.html) a paste is a big mess.

Is it possible to just moisten the flour with the right amount of water and then steam it, such that in the end it will still be mostly a powder and easy to dry?

Comment: Will you be adding hot water when backpacking, or cold? I ask because a 3-minute cook time can be easily replicated by adding hot water, then placing in an [insulated pouch](https://trailcooking.com/store/fbc-cozies/).

Comment: I would prefer just adding cold water, but could let it soak overnight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raw chickpea flour is unpleasantly bitter, but it becomes delicious when dry roasted or fried in a little oil.

It takes some practice to achieve exactly the right degree of roastedness. You will notice while dry roasting that the flour starts to become aromatic, and then smells slightly over-roasted and rather suddenly turns light brown. I recommend roasting it until just before the colour change for this purpose. Stir constantly and break up lumps to roast evenly.

This pre-roasted flour will not need further cooking. To reconstitute you simply add a little water, mix, add more water, mix, and keep going until the consistency is what you want. You can immediately eat it, you can use cold water for this, and you do not need to cook it.

You can also lightly dry roast and grind sesame seeds, probably along with the chickpea flour. Avoid grinding sesame seeds alone too finely, as they will turn into tahini.

Presumably you have access to garlic powder.

A dry substitute for lemon juice could be sumac (a type of berry which is dried and powdered), as [suggested by Chris H](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/109809/instant-hummus-pre-cooking-without-dehydrating/109819#comment175775_109819).

Comment: Interesting, I've never tried to use chickpea flour before. How would you reconstitute the flour when camping? Could you add water and wait, or would you have to cook it?

Comment: @GdD When I make hummus, I normally use dried chickpeas which I soak and then pressure-cook. But OP asks for a dehydrated version. I have made hummus from roasted chickpea flour a few times. To reconstitute you simply add a little water, mix, add more water, mix, and keep going until the consistency is what you want. You can immediately eat it, you can use cold water for this, and you do not need to cook it. But the flour must be roasted first - if it is raw it tastes horrible.

Comment: That's useful info for campers @Zanna, worth editing and adding it in I think.

Comment: +1 I'll have to try this. I'm also interested in home made dehydrated camping food. Garlic powder will be required, but perhaps dried herbs too, even if not strictly traditional.

Comment: This is a great out of the box idea. I can't wait to try this. Thank you!

Comment: You are most welcome @guest I hope you enjoy it!

Comment: @ChrisH I like to add either coriander or thyme. The latter goes amazingly with extra whole sesame seeds and chilli flakes imho

Comment: @Zanna sumac would give the tanginess missing without lemon, and is traditional. Hot smoked paprika and a pinch of cumin also work well

Comment: For lemon, you can substitute crystalized lemon juice, such as ReaLemon. It comes in small packets, each packet being equivalent to the juice of a lemon wedge. [This question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1291/85773) has some suggestions for tahini substitutions, such as grinding your own sesame seeds, or using peanut butter, which you can get in single-serve packets. Or you could pre-package a small amount of tahini in snack-sized plastic bag.

Comment: @ChrisH that's a great idea - I had forgotten about sumac.

Answer (score 1):

To toast the flour in quantity try a pressure canner.

Fill pint jars with the flour add a lid and ring then add water to the canner & cook for 60 min with a 10# weight for an hour.

The color of the finished flour is darker on the outside than in the middle, so i empty it in a bowl and mix.

Then to make hummus

-1/2C toasted flour
-2C boiling water
-1/4t salt
-1/2t powdered lemon juice(from Asian market)
-1/2t garlic powder
-1/4t cumin
-tahini to taste
-olive oil to taste

Add water to dry ingredients, after rehydrated add wet &mix.

It is easy to premix the dry ingredients & adjust to taste. The olive oil & tahini can be packaged in a plastic bag or container.